# How to call a haskell instance without explicit type

Tags: haskell

I have a class with no explicit type a.

```
> class Binaer a where
> a_zu_binaer :: a -> String
```

And I am building an instance of that class. The function `toBin` requires as input an Integer.

```
> instance Binaer Integer where
> a_zu_binaer b = toBin b
```

Doing so I get the following error:

```
Inferred type is not general enough
*** Expression    : a_zu_binaer
*** Expected type : a -> String
*** Inferred type : Integer -> String
```

Is there a way to solve this problem? I can not give an explicit type for "a"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indentation matters.

```
class Binaer a where
a_zu_binaer :: a -> String
```

This defines a class with *no methods*, and a completely unrelated `a_zu_binaer` function.
To make that into a method, indent it.

```
class Binaer a where
   a_zu_binaer :: a -> String
```

I'd recommend you write your code in a file, instead of entering it in GHCi. In GHCi, you will need to write everything on one line, or use one of the multi-line entry modes, but that's less convenient.